# How can I call methods between two classes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I have a class `A`.  During the `__init__` method of an instance of `A`;

I create these following two instances of classes `B` and `C`:

```
b = B()
c = C()
```

Once all's set, I need to call, within a method of `B`, a method from `C`.

Example:

Triggered:

```
b.call_c()
```

Does:

```
def call_c(self):
    parent.c.a_method_of_c()
```

What do I need to do to achieve this structure?

Comment: There's nothing defined named `parent` for `call_c()` to use to execute the `parent.c.a_method_of_c()` call. It needs the name of something that is an instance of `class C`, this can be passed to it as an additional argument or it could be stored in the instance of a `class B` object referred to by its `self` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how this looks if you pass the A object to both B and C as a parent/container object:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B(self)
        self.c = C(self)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def call_c(self):
        self.parent.c.a_method_of_c()

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    # whatever...
```

Or, you can just pass the C instance to B's initializer like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = C()
        self.b = B(self.c)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.cobj = c

    def call_c(self):
        self.cobj.a_method_of_c()

class C(object):
    # whatever...
```

I like the second approach better, since it cuts out the dependencies of B and C on A, and the necessity of A to implement `b` and `c` attributes.

If B and C have to call methods on each other, you can still use A to make these associations, but keep B and C ignorant of A:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()
        self.c = C()
        self.b.cobj = self.c
        self.c.bobj = self.b

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.cobj = None

    def call_c(self):
        if self.cobj is not None:
            self.cobj.a_method_of_c()
        else:
            raise Exception("B instance not fully initialized")

class C(object):
    # similar to B
```

In general, your goal is to try to avoid or at least minimize these dependencies - have a parent know about a child, but a child be ignorant of the parent. Or a container knows its contained objects, but the contained objects do not know their container. Once you add circular references (back references to a parent or container object), things can get ugly in all kinds of surprising ways. A relationship can get corrupted when one of the links gets cleared but not the reflecting link. Or garbage-collection in circular relations can get tricky (handled in Python itself, but may not be handled if these objects and relations are persisted or replicated in a framework).

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass either of `self` or `c` to `B()` so that it can know about the other object.

Comment: Ignacio, I tried passing the parent then doing parent.c but it failed. Could you please expand a little what do you mean, perhaps I made a mistake? I would paste code but I've been at this for over an hour now and I tried-deleted many ways.

Comment: If you want to make objects available to methods other than the initializer then you need to store it on the object being initialized.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to call, within a method of `B`, a method from `C`.

Basically, if the method is not a *class method* or a *static method*, then calling a method always means that you have access to the (`c`) object of the `C` class.

Have a look at the example:

```
#!python3

class B:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return 'class B object with the value ' + str(self.value)    


class C:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return 'class C object with the value ' + str(self.value)    


class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.b = B(value * 2)
        self.c = C(value * 3)

    def __str__(self):
        lst = ['class A object with the value ' + str(self.value),
               '  containing the ' + self.b.__str__(),
               '  containing also the ' + str(self.c),
               ]
        return '\n'.join(lst)


a = A(1)
print(a)
print(a.b)
print(a.c)
```

The `self.b.__str__()` is the example of calling the method of the object of the `B` class from the method of the object of the `A` class. The `str(self.c)` is the same, only called indirectly via the `str()` function.

The following is displayed:

```
class A object with the value 1
  containing the class B object with the value 2
  containing also the class C object with the value 3
class B object with the value 2
class C object with the value 3
```